# How to compare integer count with for-each counter in WSO2 BPS BPEL

Tags: variables, compare, wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

I found problem to compare result of count function with for-each counter.
I have input XML with multiple  elements.
I get count($PartnerLink1Response.return/Body/Object) at the start into unsignedInt variable which returns

```
<temporary-simple-type-wrapper>2.0</temporary-simple-type-wrapper>
```

This value I want to compare inside ForEach loop with loop variable Counter which is unsignedInt too but it returns value

```
<tns:result xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">2</tns:result>
```

This two values in If condition never match. How to compare this two values to match.

I am using WSO2 BPS 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that although you cannot compare

```
count($Response2.return/Body/Object) = $Counter
```

comparing

```
count($Response2.return/Body/Object) - $Counter = 0
```

works